# Using a method from the parent class

Tags: python, class

I want to call a method from the parent class in a child class.

I use `XX.__init__()` in my child class and call the press function from the parent class. But it fails when I run the following code:

#### Func.py

```
class PC:
 def __init__(self):
    PCKeyDis = {}
    self.PCKeyDis = PCKeyDis

 def Press(self,key):
    KeyDis = self.PCKeyDis

    if len(key)==1 and key.islower():  
        key = key.upper()
        win32api.keybd_event(KeyDis[key],0,0,0)      
        time.sleep(0.1)
        win32api.keybd_event(KeyDis[key],0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)

class PCFunc(PC):
 def __init__(self):
    pass

 def Sentence(self,string):
    PC.__init__()
    strlist = list(string)
    for i in xrange(len(strlist)):
        if strlist[i] == ' ':
            strlist[i] = 'Space'
        PC.Press(strlist[i])  #use this function
```

#### action.py

```
import Func
import win32gui
PC = Func.PC()
PCFunc = Func.PCFunc ()

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(win32gui.FindWindow(winclass,winnm))
PCFunc.Sentence(path)
```

I get:

```
unbound method Sentence() must be called with PCFunc instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? What were you *expecting* calling `PC.__init__()` in `PCFunc.Sentence` to do? Why do you create an instance of `PCFunc` and name it `PCFunc` too? And why is `PCFunc.__init__` just `pass`?! Your code so far makes very little sense to me.

Comment: The immediate problem is that you're calling `PCFunc.Sentence` like a class method when it's not a class method. The bigger problem is that the whole thing makes virtually no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the constructor of the base class, then you do it on instantiation in the `__init__()` method, not in the `Sentence()` method:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

Since `Sentence()` is an instance method, you need to call it via an instance of the class (like the error tells you):

```
pc_func = PCFunc()
pc_func.Sentence(var)
```

Here you are calling the method with an undefined variable:

```
PCFunc.Sentence(path)
```

Instead you need to give a string as parameter, so either write `Sentence('path')`, or define the variable first:

```
path = 'my path'
pc_func.Sentence(path)
```

Do not use the same name as the class name for an instance of the class:

```
PCFunc = Func.PCFunc ()
```

Otherwise the variable name storing the instance overwrites the class name.

Apart from that, it is unclear what your code is actually supposed to do. Have a look at the [Python code conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a first step to making your code more readible. Then do some research about classes and inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted does not produce the error you posted. Here is an example that will produce that error:

```
class Dog:
    def do_stuff(self, string):
        print string

d = Dog()

d.do_stuff('hello')
Dog.do_stuff(d, 'goodbye')

Dog.do_stuff('goodbye')

--output:--
hello
goodbye

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    Dog.do_stuff('goodbye')
TypeError: unbound method do_stuff() must be called with Dog instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

An `__init__()` function can also produce that error:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_stuff(self, string):
        print(string)

Dog.__init__()

--output:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
    Dog.__init__()
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Dog instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

In the line:

```
d.do_stuff('hello')
```

the fragment `d.do_stuff` causes python to create and return a `bound` method object--which is then immediately executed by the function execution operator `()` in the fragment `('hello’)`.  The bound method is *bound* to the instance `d`, hence the reason it is called a *bound* method.  A bound method automatically passes the instance it contains to the method when the method is executed.

On the other hand, when you write:

```
Dog.do_stuff(....)
```

the fragment `Dog.do_stuff` causes python to create and return an *unbound* method.  An unbound method does not contain an instance, so when an unbound method is executed by the function execution operator `()`, you must manually pass an instance.  (In `python3`, things changed and you can pass anything as the first argument--an instance of the class isn't required.)